# NativeProcess is not Supported AIR 3.2 Desktop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I am creating an application which capture the screenshot of the desktop.
When I'm compiling and run the application on Flash, only than it will works fine but when I published it with  AIR 3.2 Desktop. Than It will not supported the NativeProcess.
I am running the application on Mac Machine.

Here is the below code which I am using:

```
        if (NativeProcess.isSupported)
        {
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
            if (Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") > -1)
            {
                file = file.resolvePath("bin/");
            }
            else if (Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf("mac") > -1)
            {
                file = file.resolvePath("/usr/sbin/screencapture/");
                trace(" in "+file.nativePath);
                status.text = file.nativePath;
            }
            var str = "screencapture" + String(count) + ".png";
            trace(" String "+str);
            var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
            args[0] = str;
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
            nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.desktopDirectory;

            process = new NativeProcess();
            process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

        }
        else
        {
            trace("Native Process not supported");
            status.text = " Native Process not supported";
        }
```

Any Help is highly appreciated

Comment: are you using the extendedDesktop profile?

Comment: Yes I used the extendedDesktop profile but still facing the issue.   <supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>

Comment: Have you tried [`File.openWithDefaultApplication()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication())? or would that not be appropriate here?